# AKS - cannot get resource priorityclasses at cluster scope

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I encounter a weird error once I try to install a helm chart that contains a priorityclass.

> Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists.
> Unable to continue with install: could not get information about the
> resource: priorityclasses.scheduling.k8s.io "svc-placeholder" is
> forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:svc:svc-sp" cannot get resource
> "priorityclasses" in API group "scheduling.k8s.io" at the cluster
> scope: Azure does not have opinion for this user.

Why is the helm trying to list priorityclasses at cluster scope even though I install everything inside a dedicated namespace with `helm upgrade --namespace` ..

any ideas?